# Having a grammar issue with beginning a sentence with "your results" and describing where the results came from sounds awkward

Tags: grammar

I am a native English speaker and I'm essentially trying to say

"How to interpret your results (that came from a Specific Test)"

but it sounds weird when I read it no matter how I try to specify the test that gave the person the results.

"How to interpret your results of The Test I Made You Take" sounds wrong.

"How to interpret your results from The Test I Made You Take" sounds wrong too.

"How to interpret your results that came from The Test I Made You Take" sounds clunky.

And because The Test I Made You Take is its own entity, I can't change the "the" to "your," as I would to change "your results of the blood test" to "the results of your blood test."

I suppose I could change the structure of the sentence and this is in no way pressing but I am curious about the answer!! Thanks!!

Comment: First of all, none of those examples is a question or a complete sentence. Are you asking *How can I … ?* or trying to state *This is how to …*? Or is it actually a title or heading, which can be a sentence fragment? What is the context for its use?

Comment: (I can think of several ways of addressing this, but it depends on the particular context. If this is a title or heading, what is the first sentence that comes after?)

Comment: I was intending on using it as a subtitle, so for example I would title my piece So You Found Out Your Spirit Animal: How to Interpret Your Results of The Interesting Spirit Animal Test. While I understand that this could easily be fixed by using the name of the test as the title, I was wondering if there was a work-around!!

Comment: Interpreting your Spirit Animal Test results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it sounds strange is because the words used in the title of the test lend themselves to be parsed as part of the grammar of the main text.

Based on comments under the question, I'll use the following as the original title:

> ？So You Found Yourself: How to Interpret Your Results of The Test I Made You Take

This uses title caps following the guidance of *The Chicago Manual of Style*, as provided by the [Title Case Converter](https://titlecaseconverter.com/) tool. However, I've made the manual change of capitalizing *The*, since it's part of a proper name.

---

The first thing that can be done is to visually offset the title of the test from the rest of the text. Since capital letters are already being used for most of the words in the title itself, they are insufficient in terms of signalling the unique nature of the test title:

> So You Found Yourself: How to Interpret Your Results of *The Test I Made You Take*

---

Second, consider an analogous, but more common, phrase:

> How to interpret your driving test results.

This phrase doesn't use a proper name, but what it does do is put *results* at the end of the sentence.

It suggests another alteration to the title being worked on:

> So You Found Yourself: How to Interpret Your *The Test I Made You Take* Results.

Although this is better, it's still not great.

---

A third modification is to use an acronym. Acronyms, in many cases, make it easier to deal with a long phrase in a manageable way:

> So You Found Yourself: How to Interpret Your TIMYT Results

Note that I dropped the first *T* from the acronym. Not all acronyms need to faithfully reproduce every letter in the phrase they represent.

This is now actually quite comprehensible, and it doesn't cause any confusion in terms of parsing the sentence. However, people might not know what TIMYT means at this point.

If the audience *does* know what TIMYT means, then it can be left as is. But if it could cause confusion on the part of some readers, then that needs to be addressed.

---

The final modification is to explain the acronym:

> ✔ So You Found Yourself: How to Interpret Your TIMYT (*The Test I Made You Take*) Results

Normally acronyms appear on first use in parentheses after the phrase they represent. But that's not always the case. Depending on the requirement, the acronym can appear first, and the phrase it represents can appear in parentheses.

In this case, putting the phrase in parentheses helps with the visual separation between it and the rest of the sentence.

In the body of the article, you could define TIMYT one more time, but then use it in place of the longer phrase on every other use. Using the acronym will make it easier to read in general.

---

This is not necessarily the *only* way of resolving the problem, but it's at least one method that makes sense, based on a series of style decisions that help improve the readability of the title.

Comment: Wow thank you, I appreciate the multiple solutions!! That answers my question!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your statements sound wrong is that is that there is an unnecessary double reference to whose results are being described. While many modifiers do not imply who took the tests, "The test I made you take" clearly implies that the results are yours. Given that, it is redundant to state "your results".

> "How to interpret the results of The Test I Made You Take"

Is perfectly correct and identifies the results as yours.

Comment: I was using "The Test I Made You Take" as a placeholder so I understand that it is made obvious that the results are "yours," but replacing it with something that isn't as telling sounds strange to me, for example "How to interpret your results of/from The Panda Test..." I am considering changing it to "the results" instead, so thank you!!

Comment: The answer would be completely different if the statement didn't already involve "you". "Sounds wrong" is often a subtle thing that depends on the exact phrase. If you are wanting to ask about a phrase that doesn't involve "you" please edit the question. "How to interpret the results of The Panda Test" would not be making it clear it was *your* results.

Answer (score -1):

How to interpret the results of the test I made you take. Sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, using the word "the" sounds correct, however I was hoping to use "your" so as to connect to the audience a bit more tangibly, thank you though!!